the execution reverted when I call a certain method from my ERC 721 smart contract using web3js
These are my methods for adding and retrieving of records from my smart contract:
// Function to retrieve records of a patient
function getRecords(address patientAddress) public view returns(Record[] memory) {
    require(hasRole(PATIENT_ROLE, patientAddress), "Address is not a valid patient");
    Record[] memory records = _patientRecords[msg.sender];
    require(records.length > 0, "No records found for the patient");
    return records;
}

// Function to add record for a patient
function addRecord(address patientAddress, string memory cid) public {
    require(hasRole(DOCTOR_ROLE, msg.sender), "Caller is not a doctor and can't add records");
    Record memory newRecord = Record({
        cid: cid,
        timestamp: block.timestamp,
        doctor: msg.sender
    });
    _patientRecords[patientAddress].push(newRecord);
    emit RecordAdded(patientAddress, cid, msg.sender);
}

mapping(address => Record[]) private _patientRecords;

Problem
When I call it from Remix it's working fine, and I get the data, but when I use it from my dApp then it's throwing execution reverted, Metamask RPC error.
I verified the address and it is correct.
The weird thing is that I used web3.js for all others method and they're working fine, but I can't understand the problem with getRecords().
EDIT:
Now, I am getting MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted: No records found for the patient.
The input for this function is a wallet address: 0xb910fAdf12d6617d6F5608331881d482f6F654E2
and if I try executing the getRecords() function from REMIX IDE, I'm getting an array of one tuple.
Here's the JS code snippet for calling the function:
export const getRecordsFromChain = async (patientAddress: string) => {
    try {
        const hasRole = await contract.methods.hasSpecificRole(patientAddress).call();
        if (hasRole) {
            return await contract.methods.getRecords(patientAddress).call();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error getting records!");
        throw error;
    }
}


Can you share the minimum reproducible code utilizing web3.js for calling the getRecords function which is reverting?

export const getRecordsFromChain = async (patientAddress:string) => {
const hasRole = await contract.methods.hasSpecificRole(patientAddress).call();
if (!hasRole) {
const receipt = await contract.methods.getRecords(patientAddress).call();
}
}

I think, it would be great if you add the code by editing your question instead of adding in the comment. Thanks.

Also, please provide the hardcoded inputs as per the reverting transaction.

I edit my question, thank you for advice.

Can you also share the contract address and ABI that you're using?
